# The bind value at index 1 is null, getting data from from asyncstorage in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I am triyng to generate buttons, with data from multiple arrays.

One of these arrays is dynamic, and its getting generated at constructor().

Problem is. When i try to navigate to screen, i get an error message saying " the bind value at index 1 is null ". The error does not point to any line inside my code, instead, it says the issue have something to do with sqlite and asyncstorage.

Im not sure why this is happening, but maybe it have something to do with the generatedData state not being initialized correctly.

I dont know what to do to solve this, any help would be appreciatted.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

class DataApp extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      dataLocalIds: [
        "data1Data",
        "data2Data",
        "data3Data",
        "data4Data",
        "data5Data",
        "data6Data"
      ],
      dataLabel: [
        "[ data 1 ]",
        "[ data 2 ]",
        "[ data 3 ]",
        "[ data 4 ]",
        "[ data 5 ]",
        "[ data 6 ]",
      ],
      generatedData: [],
    }

    this.state.dataLocalIds.map((value, index) => {
      this.data = this.getDatas(value);
    })
  }

  async getDatas(value) {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(value).then(val => {
        let jsonInit = {};
        jsonInit[value] = value;
        let newArray = this.state.generatedData;
        newArray.push(jsonInit);
        this.setState(generatedData: newArray);
        return JSON.parse(val)
      });
      return value
    } catch (err) {
      throw err
    }
  }

  renderScreen = () => {
      var myData =  JSON.parse(this.state.generatedData);
      return (
          {this.state.dataLabel.map((item, index) => {
            return(
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={}>
                <Text>{this.state.generatedData[index] === "{}" ? item : "foo: " + generatedData.foo + " / bar: " + generatedData.bar}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              )
            })}
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.renderScreen()
    );
  }
}
export default DataApp;
```

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

i have this problem and it was for that i have sended null value to `AsyncStorage.getItem()` and when i changed it. it solved.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can occur when you are trying to use `AsyncStorage` **before** the app has been started/registered.

If it is the case, try moving the code that calls `AsyncStorage` to a `componenDidMount`/`useEffect`hook (you can render a loading/empty view while this logic is being executed).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error however using a library that wraps AsyncStorage. Its called react-native-simple-store. The problem was I was trying to get data from the storage using a variable that wasn't ready yet (it was null/undefined). This variable would be ready only after a certain time after rendering. So what I did is add an if condition, if its null dont do anything, when the state changes and the component re-renders, the variable is ready now so it will enter the if statement and access storage.

Answer (score 0):

First you should `import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'`

then you have to define any unique key

`const ASYNC_STORAGE_COMMENTS_KEY = 'ANYTHING_UNIQUE_STRING'`

and while calling `AsyncStorage.setItem` your first parameter should be `ASYNC_STORAGE_COMMENTS_KEY` and second parameter should be you json data with stringify

e.g. `AsyncStorage.setItem(ASYNC_STORAGE_COMMENTS_KEY, JSON.stringify(data));`

and for fetching

`const your_var = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ASYNC_STORAGE_COMMENTS_KEY);`